# How do i run Instiki?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I know very little in ruby and Git. I'm trying to set up [instiki](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/wiki/instiki/show/Installation) which is a wiki software. I'm using windows. I have downloaded some ruby gems ( I have no idea what these are ). I have ruby and Git. I successfully downloaded instiki from the ruby gems website along with all of its dependencies. I can find these using "gem environment" command. Now , how do I run instiki ? When I type "ruby instiki" in the rubby shell , it gives an error which says that I should run "ruby bundle install" When I do this , it tells me that I have to install Git , Which I already have.In short , How do I run a ruby gem ? (In this case , Instiki )

Please , note that I do not have the slightest idea what a ruby gem is. Nor do I know what "ruby bundle install" should do.

Comment: hmmm you may not like it but linux is a better environment for ruby development

Comment: I think so , I just do not want to learn ruby development right now. I just want to get a quick fix to this problem at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

check these sites :

http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?t=138474

https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/wiki/instiki/show/Installation

RubyGems is a package manager for the Ruby programming language that provides a standard format for distributing Ruby programs and libraries (in a self-contained format called a "gem"), a tool designed to easily manage the installation of gems, and a server for distributing them.

Comment: I did that. The problem is that when I type "instiki" An error report says that I have to use "bundle install" . When I use that , it says I have to set up Git.

Comment: The message is : "Fetching git://github.com/distler/maruku.git You need to install git to use gems from git repositories"

Comment: search on google : how to fix error Fetching git://github.com/distler/maruku.git You need to install git to use gems from git repositories

Comment: I have found the solution. Windows cmd must be configured by adding the git path to the system environmental variables. This fixed the problem. However , There is another problem.